# Alpine Linux VirtualBox VM With xfce4 Desktop Not Able to Use Full Screen Resolution

Tags: virtualbox, xfce, resolution, alpine-linux, slim

I have an installation of alpine linux running in a virtualbox vm with slim + xfce4 for the desktop engine.

Kernel Version: I have tried with both the latest (3.6.2) Standard and Virtual Kernel from https://alpinelinux.org/downloads/

I have not been able to get the guest to utilize the entire screen resolution, instead it is only able to go up to 1024x768. I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out what I'm missing/doing wrong. Below are the steps I've taken:

I followed the steps in this [video exactly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_bsycXrFcI)

**Standard Alpine Linux install**

- Using all repositories: apk update && apk upgrade
- setup-xorg-base
- apk add alpine-desktop
- apk add xfce4
- apk add thunar-volman
- apk add faenza-icon-theme
- apk add slim
- rc-service dbus start
- rc-update add dbus
- rc-service udev start
- rc-service add udev
- rc-update add slim
- reboot

**Virtualbox Specific Packages:**

*Standard Kernel:*

apk add virtualbox-guest-modules-grsec virtualbox-additions-grsec virtualbox-guest-additions-5.1.26-r0

*Virtual Kernel:*

apk add virtualbox-guest-additions-5.1.26-r0
apk add virtualbox-guest-modules-grsec
"apk add virtualbox-guest-modules-grsec" give the following warning message:

depmod could not open /lib/modules/4.9.44-0-hardened/modules.order

I did NOT do the following:

apk add virtualbox-additions-grsec
Because that breaks my installation, only allows me to boot into the command prompt and spams the following error:

tty port_close_start: tty->count = 1 port count = 2

**Virtualbox Settings:**

- Version: 5.1.26 r117224 (Qt5.6.2)
- VirtualBox > Preferences > Display > Maximum Guest Screen Size: None
- View > Auto-resize Guest Display checked (It's greyed out, can't select it)
- VM Settings > Display > Screen: Video Memory 128MB, 1 Monitor, 100% scale factor, Enable 3D Acceleration turned on

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by following the steps below.
Display screen graphics controller (G): VBoxSVGA selected.

```
$ sudo apk add xf86-video-vboxvideo xf86-video-intel xf86-video-vesa  
$ sudo apk add xf86-input-synaptics  
$ sudo apk add virtualbox-guest-additions  
$ sudo rc-update add virtualbox-guest-additions default  
$ sudo echo vboxpci    >> /etc/modules  
$ sudo echo vboxdrv    >> /etc/modules  
$ sudo echo vboxnetflt >> /etc/modules  

$ sudo apk update  
$ sudo apk upgrade --update-cache --available  

$ sudo reboot
```

Comment: ``sudo echo`` normally doesn't work.  Is that really what you did?

Answer (score 1):

The steps I actually took were a little different.
Thank you for your comments.

I solved this problem by following the steps below.
Display screen graphics controller (G): VBoxSVGA selected.

# apk add xf86-video-vboxvideo xf86-video-intel xf86-video-vesa

# apk add xf86-input-synaptics

# apk add virtualbox-guest-additions

# rc-update add virtualbox-guest-additions default

# echo vboxpci >> /etc/modules

# echo vboxdrv >> /etc/modules

# echo vboxnetflt >> /etc/modules

# apk update

# apk upgrade --update-cache --available

# reboot

Comment: Please get your accounts merged, *edit* your other answer and delete this one.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should check your first line beginning apk should you have not written GUEST 
Your line reads as follows

apk add virtualbox-additions-grsec